# Cannot copy html formatted string to clipboard

Tags: c#, html, winforms, office-interop

I am trying to copy html formatted string from my database to a word document. I need to be able to restore formatting like bullets. Using the below code, I get an exception

> "The specified data type is unavailable."

Below is the code to copy to clipboard and write to word document.

```
DataObject clipDO = new DataObject();
clipDO.SetData(DataFormats.Html, HtmlClipboardData(temp));
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipDO, true));
thread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph oPara = wordApp.Selection.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
object pasteType = WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML;
oPara.Range.PasteSpecial(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, pasteType, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

The code stopped working now. When it did work earlier, it would not copy html to clipboard. It would write to word doc, previous contents of clipboard.
My helper method for adding header to the html string is below.

```
    private static string HtmlClipboardData(string html)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        string Header = @"
        Version: 1.0
        StartHTML: {0:000000}
        EndHTML: {1:000000}
        StartFragment: {2:000000}
        EndFragment: {3:000000}
        ";
        string HtmlPrefix = @"
        !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//TR""
        html
        head
        meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=""text/html; charset={0}""
        head
        body
        !--StartFragment--
        ";
        HtmlPrefix = string.Format(HtmlPrefix, encoding.WebName);

        string HtmlSuffix = @"
        <!--EndFragment-->
        </body>
        </html>
        ";

        // Get lengths of chunks
        int HeaderLength = encoding.GetByteCount(Header);
        HeaderLength -= 16; // extra formatting characters {0:000000}
        int PrefixLength = encoding.GetByteCount(HtmlPrefix);
        int HtmlLength = encoding.GetByteCount(html);
        int SuffixLength = encoding.GetByteCount(HtmlSuffix);

        // Determine locations of chunks
        int StartHtml = HeaderLength;
        int StartFragment = StartHtml + PrefixLength;
        int EndFragment = StartFragment + HtmlLength;
        int EndHtml = EndFragment + SuffixLength;

        // Build the data
        sb.AppendFormat(Header, StartHtml, EndHtml, StartFragment, EndFragment);
        sb.Append(HtmlPrefix);
        sb.Append(html);
        sb.Append(HtmlSuffix);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

The problem is that the html string is not copied to clipboard. When I have some special content(like content copied from command prompt) in clipboard already, PasteSpecial works and pastes that data into my word doc.

Comment: Why are you doing the work on a thread?  What type of application is this (console, winforms, WPF)?  Also, what line is throwing that error?  The paste line or the clipboard set line?

Comment: This is in an asp.net application. I am doing that in a thread because otherwise I get "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it." exception.  The problem is that I cant copy content through code to Clipboard.

Comment: You are asking for a world of hurt by using the clipboard and word from ASP.net applications.  First of all word isn't supported on servers and there is a [long document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) explaining a myriad of problems you could run into. Also, by using the global clipboard, you will probably run into race conditions if you have more than one user using your system.  My suggestion is to look into alternatives that can create documents on the server in a thread safe (and non-UI) manner.

Comment: The HtmlPrefix does not have `<>" but the HtmlSuffix does so I assume that is not just a matter of formatting in the post. If that is what the code was like then this problem was unique to that specific program. If a sample of what the function returned was provided then the problem would probably have been obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DataFormats.Text instead.